# React "Warning: Invalid value for prop `map` on tag"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

"Warning: Invalid value for prop `map` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM"

This Warning shows up on some occasions. Here is my code this is related to:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import "./css/main.css"


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h2>Hello</h2>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

Obviously there is no prop at all on the h2 tag .I hope somebody does have an idea.....

Comment: "Warning: Invalid value for prop map on <h2>  tag." is the original message.

Comment: react-dom render takes only ONE element in return.